# Selecting the current element when instantiating a JQuery widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm attempting to construct a dynamic URL for a JQuery auto complete widget, but I can't seem to find a way to reference the current element when I am instantiating the widget. $(this) and this reference the HTMLDocument object instead of the element which is currently having the widget instantiated, is there a way of changing this? Here is my code:

```
$(function() 
{   
    $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
      source: baseUrl+"autocomplete/"+window.filter+"/"+$(this).attr("name"),
      minLength: 2
    });
}
```

This is the current URL that is created:

> http://example.com/autocomplete/products/undefined?term=test

But it should be:

> http://example.com/autocomplete/products/filter-name?term=test

**Edit**

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phily245/70zjn7tx/8/)

Comment: Could you make a fiddle ofit not working?

Comment: @JackZelig I've added it to the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `this` refers to the document object, which doesn't have a name property, hence the error you are seeing.

You need to initialize the autocomplete differently:

```
var filter = "products";
$(".autocomplete").each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).autocomplete({
    source: "http://example.com/autocomplete/" + filter + "/" + el.name,
    minLength: 2
  });
});
```

And that should work.

Answer (score 1):

You're not inside a different scope, so `this` will refer to whatever it was already referring to.  You need to loop over each `.autocomplete` element:

```
$(".autocomplete").each(function(i, e) {
    //both "e" and "this" now refer to the element
    $(e).autocomplete({
      source: baseUrl+"autocomplete/"+window.filter+"/"+ $(e).attr("name"),
      minLength: 2
    });
});
```